# Socket.io Redis Server Broadcast

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, redis, socket.io

I'm missing something really basic here. I have two very standard express processes with socket io. I'm trying to get a server broadcast on one process to broadcast the same message to another servers clients. I have following setup:

```
    var server = require('http').createServer(app);
  var socketio = require('socket.io')(server, {
    serveClient: (config.env !== 'production'),
    path: '/socket.io-client'
  });

  require('./config/express')(app);
  require('./routes')(app);

  server.listen(config.port, config.ip, function () {
    logger.info('Express server listening on %d, in %s mode', config.port, app.get('env'));
  });

  var redis = require('socket.io-redis');
  var adapter = redis({ host: config.redis.uri, port: config.redis.port });

  adapter.pubClient.on('error', function(){
    logger.error('Error on pub client');
  });
  adapter.subClient.on('error', function(){
    logger.error('Error on sub client');
  });

  socketio.adapter(adapter);

  require('./config/socketio')(socketio);
```

Then my socket io file is:

```
module.exports = function (socketio) {
  //listen to other server broadcasts
  socketio.on('socket.io#/#', function(data) {
    logger.debug('received message from other process');
  });

  //client connection code
  socketio.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.address = socket.handshake.address !== null ?
            socket.handshake.address + ':' + socket.handshake.address.port :
            process.env.DOMAIN;

    socket.connectedAt = new Date();

    // Call onDisconnect.
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
      onDisconnect(socket);
      logger.debug('[%s] DISCONNECTED', socket.address);
    });

    // Call onConnect.
    onConnect(socketio, socket);
    logger.debug('[%s] CONNECTED', socket.address);
  });
};
```

From a different server I'm just calling a standard emit

```
socketio.emit('message', object);
```

In terms of debugging, I load up the redis cli and check the channels that are created:

```
1) "socket.io#/#"
2) "socket.io-sync#request#/#"
```

I even run `SUBSCRIBE "socket.io#/#"` in the cli and can see the message I'm trying to get on the other server displayed via the cli.

This seems so basic, how do I properly subscribe to events on the redis channel `'socket.io#/#'`?

**EDIT**: So I figured out that I receive messages on my other process if I do

```
socketio.sockets.adapter.subClient.on('message', function (channel, message) {
    logger.warn('GOT STUFF ');
  });
```

However here I'm just going straight to the redis sub client. The channel and message are just buffers of non usable data.  Isn't this suppose to provide a higher level of abstraction?

**EDIT 2**: I've got it "mostly" working now.  Doing this:

```
socketio.sockets.adapter.subClient.on('message', function (channel, message) {
    logger.warn('GOT STUFF ');

    socketio.sockets.in(channel).emit(message);
  });
```

Turns on the socket interface will take the channel and message buffers directly.  Now to my next issue, instead of doing `socketio.emit(message, doc);` I want to do this `socketio.sockets.in(doc._id).emit('message;, doc);`. Basically i only want it to end in clients that are a part of that room.  Doesn't quite seem to be working as is...

Comment: hi @sauce .. have you found a solution to this... please share it.